# How do I create a table in PHP filled with new objects

Tags: php

I'm looking to build an HTML table within my `outputAsTable()` method. However, I have tried many ways with no correct result. Can some one help with the HTML/PHP code needed or some pointers to what it is I need to build a table displaying the new book objects as I'm new to PHP and still learning.

```
<?php

class Book {
    public $author; //property
    public $title; //property
    public $publisher; //property
    public $year; //property

    # constructor for each new book
    public function __construct($author, $title, $publisher, $year) {
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->publisher = $publisher;
        $this->year = $year;
    }   

    # method to display new book objects in a table
    public function outputAsTable($book) {

        //build a table and display new book objects

    }
}

# an array of books
$books = array(
    new Book("author1", "title1", "publisher1", "year1"),
    new Book("author2", "title2", "publisher2", "year2"),
    new Book("author3", "title3", "publisher3", "year3"),
    new Book("author4", "title4", "publisher4", "year4"),
    new Book("author5", "title5", "publisher5", "year5")
);

foreach($books as $book) {
    echo outputAsTable($book);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to do:

1. Replace the foreach with: (the foreach will move into the output function)

   ```
   Books::outputAsTable($books);
   ```
2. Change the class function definition to be static, and the param:

   ```
   public static function outputAsTable($books)
   ```
3. Then in `outputAsTable` function:

   ```
   public static function outputAsTable($books) {
       echo '<table>
             <tr>
                <th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Publisher</th><th>Year</th>
             </tr>';

       foreach($books as $book) {
           echo "<tr><td>{$book->author}</td>
                     <td>{$book->title}</td>
                     <td>{$book->publisher}</td>
                     <td>{$book->year}</td></tr>";
       }

       echo '</table>';
   }
   ```

The reason I used the `static` route is because you already have an array of `Book` objects. An instance of `Book` would be needed to use the `outputAsTable` function without it being static. With the function being static, you can pass the `$books` array to use within the function as needed.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the solution and explanation to using the static route.